# Does hive query always do full scan, even if it is in equals condition?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create an external Hive table that maps to a **DynamoDB** table like the official documentation says.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb(hashKey STRING, recordTimeStamp BIGINT, fullColumn map<String, String>)
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
    TBLPROPERTIES ( 
     "dynamodb.table.name" = "myTable",
     "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "hashKey:HashKey,recordTimeStamp:RangeKey");
```

But doing a query using the hash key it seems it is doing a full scan table.

```
hive> select * from dynamodb where hashKey="test";
```

Any suggestions on that? Thanks

Comment: This depends more on dynamodb architecture  than Hive

Comment: But yes, it needs to scan the table to filter the results where your condition is true...

Comment: @cricket_007, oops my bad I will delete my comment.

Comment: so, it will bring to memory all table, and then filtering by the condition....